# sharepoint designer 2013 is not installing

Tags: 2013, designer

When I am trying to install Sharepoint designer 2013 on Windows 10, the installation doesn't start. Only the license page appears for a second, then disappears and setup doesn't respond. Not even an error pop-ups.

Comment: try to restart your computer and install again. You can try clearing the cache, running the set up with admin rights.

Comment: Is the Architecture of SP Designer 2013 the same as Office, x86 or x64?

Comment: I had the same problem. I had an old Office-version installed (Office2010).